# How to create custom pagination in ZK

Tags: listbox, zk, zul

I could not find any tutorial regarding custom pagination in zk. ZK provides it's default pagination and it's quite good but my customer needs different pagination style. So, how can I create custom pagination in ZK. Any help please ?

I have a listbox like this :

```
<listbox id=”bidLbx” mold=”paging”>
   <listitem>
     ...
   </listitem>
</listbox>
```

It displays ZK's default pagination like: `1 2 3 4 5 Next Last` but with out option to select per page row number. So, I need my own Buttons and per page dropdown option.

Comment: If you just need the dromdown option for page size, I think you can use combobox and call Listbox#setPageSize while combobox selection changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write the codes to control the pagination buttons as we require, i.e. **`First` `Previous` `1` `2` `3` `4` `5` `Next` `Last`**.

We just take reference of that id i.e. `bidLbx` and do coding. We need to get certain values and use those values to control the buttons.

This gives the current page no: `bidLbx.getPaginal().getActivePage();`

This gives the total number of rows: `bidLbx.getPaginal().getTotalSize();`

This sets the Page Size (i.e. no. of rows per page): `bidLbx.getPaginal().setPageSize();`

This gives the no. of pages: `bidLbx.getPaginal().getPageCount();`

and don't forget to disable the default paging.

```
<listbox id=”bidLbx” mold=”paging”>
    ...
    <zscript>
            <![CDATA[
                bidLbx.getPagingChild().setVisible(false);
                ]]>
    </zscript>
</listbox>
```

**First button Example:**

```
<button id="first" label="First" style="margin:10px; padding:5px;">
   <attribute name="onClick">
      <![CDATA[
          bidLbx.getPaginal().setActivePage(0);
      ]]>
   </attribute>
</button>
```

**Dropdown perpage combobox:**

```
<combobox id="pageSize" value="20" style="width:50px;" readonly="true">
    <comboitem label="5"></comboitem>
    <comboitem label="10"></comboitem>
        <attribute name="onCreate">
           <![CDATA[
             String ps = pageSize.getValue();
         int pSize = Integer.parseInt(ps);
         bidLbx.getPaginal().setPageSize(pSize);
      ]]>
        </attribute>
       <attribute name="onChange">
     <![CDATA[
           String ps = pageSize.getValue();
           int pSize = Integer.parseInt(ps);
       bidLbx.getPaginal().setPageSize(pSize);
     ]]>
      </attribute>
</combobox>
```

If you have still problem do comment.

Comment: can you share me the per page dropdown please ?

Comment: Ok, I have added that above.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use [CSS](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Style%20Guide/ZK%20Class%20Concept/Overwriting) to change the style of the [`Paging`](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Style_Guide/XUL_Component_Specification/Paging/os) component or
2. just create your own paging component with zk components or pure
   [html](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Essential_Components/Html)
   and listen to [onClick Events](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Essentials/Introduction_to_ZK/Event_Driven_Programming), if you use zk components, or 
   [fire events to the server with javascript](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Client-side_Reference/Communication/AU_Requests/Client-side_Firing), if you use html,
    
   and handle the paging logic by your self.

For styling also refer to:
[Customize Look and Feel - Part 1](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2011/December/Customize_Look_and_Feel_of_ZK_Components_Using_CSS3)
[Customize Look and Feel - Part 2](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small%20Talks/2012/March/Customize%20Look%20and%20Feel%20of%20ZK%20Components%20Using%20CSS3%20-%20Part%202)