# zk dropdown list move from combobox

Tags: css, combobox, zk

I have the following problem using combobox: the drop down list moves from the combobox.

When the itemlist go outside the screen, the drop down list go on the top and is not anymore linked to combobox

I've changed the style (and set this as combobox class) in this way to change height of the popup:

```
.MyCmb.z-combobox-popup.z-combobox-open.z-combobox-shadow { 
    height: 100px !important;
}
```

I see that the dropdown list is little than before but when i press the combobox button i see first the list bigger (as usual) and then will be resized to 100px...

What i've to do to avoid that dropdown list move from combobox?

thank you

Comment: Is not working... I have tried this example but without results: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861187/how-to-create-custom-pagination-in-zk

Comment: look at this :http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/combobox/customizable_combobox